# JPA Eclipselink EntityManager remains in memory when REQUIRES_NEW is used

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I noticed that there is a memory leak in Eclipselink version 2.5.2. 
When I use TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW, to run sub tasks in their own transaction, some instances of Eclipselink are accumulating in memory.

For example the call of this method from a other Stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
...
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void removeFromQueue(Long id) {
    DelayedUpdateQueue item = em.getReference(DelayedUpdateQueue.class, id);
    em.remove(item);
}
```

[image: Netbeans Profiler]

I see that using REQUIRES_NEW must create another instance of the EntityManager and also open a second connection to the PostgreSQL database. But why is it never cleared?

If I call the method without using REQUIRES_NEW the amount EntityManagerImpl stays very low. < 3

Clicking Garbage Collection in Profiler also does not remove them.

**UPDATE:**

After using a newer version of the jdbc driver and switch the datasource from XADataSource (not really needed in the project) to ConnectionPoolDatasource the problem disappears.

```
Old driver version: postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc4.jar
New driver version: postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar
```

Thank you for your feedback.